# Image count (1/10) in a slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, slider

It's a slide of images that have auto fadeIn and also I can control it by the arrows in the bottom left (next and prev arrows). The problem it's that I want to show a total of images and the current number of the one we are watching (like the numbering between the arrows), I have made the markup but I have search a lot on how to programming the number but couldn't find anything similar. Can someone help me out please?

This is the markup:

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <ul id="slides">
        <li><img src="img/project_image.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="img/project_image2.jpg"/></li>
        <li><img src="img/project_image3.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="img/project_image4.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="project_navigation" class="clearfix">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li id="prev"><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
        <div class="project_number">
            <p>10/12</p>
        </div>
        <li id="next"><a href="#">Next</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is how I call the slider:

```
  $("#slideshow").css("overflow", "hidden");

  $("ul#slides").cycle({
      fx: 'fade',
      pause: 1,
      prev: '#prev',
      next: '#next'
  });
```

And i'm using this plugin:
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('#slideshow').cycle({
        fx:       'fade',
        timeout:   0,
        prev: '#prev',
        next: '#next',
        after:     onAfter
    });
});

function onAfter(curr,next,opts) {
    var caption = 'Image ' + (opts.currSlide + 1) + ' of ' + opts.slideCount;
    $('#caption').html(caption);
}
```

You can use the `after` callback (or `before`) to change the content of a div with a function. This function will run after (or before) each transition.

http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/VhcgL/

Comment: You'll need to change #caption to .project_number p and sync the ID's for next and previous up but it will work.

Comment: The code works (http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/VhcgL/). You need to add both parts.

Comment: See how the onAfter function is ran 1st thing so you don't need any text in the caption div to start with. Also I've paused the slideshow with timeout: 0 instead of pause.

Answer (score 0):

See for onPrevNextEvent callback function of this plugin.

```
$("ul#slides").cycle({
      fx: 'fade',
      pause: 1,
      prev: '#prev',
      next: '#next',
      onPrevNextEvent : function(isNext, zeroBasedSlideIndex, slideElement){
           $('.project_number p').text(zeroBasedSlideIndex+'/'+$("ul#slides img").length);
      }
  });
```

Doesnt test this code, but maybe onPrevNextEvent is fired before the cycle is done. In this case, you should look at isNext parameter or onAfter event.

Comment: this one works, but it shows the numbering after I click first on an arrow, at the load of the page it doesn't shows anything, why is that?

Comment: I updated it on the webtest so you can see it what's happening

Comment: Because it's looking for the next / prev event which hasn't fired until the nav is clicked. See my answer for one that will do that.

Comment: Ya, you should look at SpaceBeers answer using onAfter event then.